# How to set model field default the same as OneToOneField attribute value?

Tags: django, django-models

There are `Lecture` and `Task` models. Every lecture has a topic. And every task has a topic and a lecture.

```py
class Lecture(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)


class Task(models.Model):
    lecture = models.OneToOneField(Lecture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        blank=False,
    )
```

I want to set `Task.topic` value the same as `Lecture.topic` this task refers to. For example:

```py
lecture1 = Lecture('Awesome topic')
lecture1.save()

task1 = Task(lecture1)
task1.save()
# here task1.topic must be 'Awesome topic'
```

I've tried this thing:

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    lecture = models.OneToOneField(Lecture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        blank=False,
        default=lecture.topic
    )
```

but have

> 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'topic'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the save method and do the desired logic before the actual save:

```
class Task(models.Model):

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.topic = self.lecture.topic
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a reason to keep `topic` in `Task`? It is redundant.